# Close all ImageJ 3D viewer windows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using Fiji (a distribution of ImageJ) to get a 3D viewer in Matlab. I would like to close all "3D viewer windows" at once. "Close (all)" function of Matlab does not take care of these windows. Is there an easy way to close all these windows at once instead of clicking "x" for all of them?